# Why printk doesn't print message in kernel log(dmesg)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, printk

I wrote small kernel module code as mentioned below,
I am testing it in `ubuntu 14.04`

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int init_mod_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "My module inserted\n ");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_mod_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "My module removed\n ");
}

module_init(init_mod_func);
module_exit(cleanup_mod_func);


MODULE_AUTHOR("Ankur");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("TEST MODULE");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Now when I compile and insert above module using `insmod` I don't see printk message in the dmesg. However after module removal using `rmmod` I see both the printk messages.

**With closure look, I found out that it is happening because of `space` after `\n` in the printk.**
However I don't get why it is like that.

```
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ sudo dmesg -C /dev/null
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ sudo insmod testmod.ko 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ dmesg
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ 
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ sudo rmmod testmod
ankur:~/temp/tmp$ dmesg
[ 4062.140441] My module inserted
[ 4062.140441]  
[ 4073.324994] My module removed
[ 4073.324994]
```

Answer (score 8):

The kernel log ring buffer behaves as if it were line-buffered, as it can be seen in the implementation:

- [in `vprintk_emit`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1726) you can see how it marks a buffer to be flushed/buffered based on the existence of a trailing newline
- [in `log_output`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1685) you can see the actual code which takes care of flushing or buffering the message

As it is evident, your messages do not contain trailing newlines. Had you deleted the trailing space, you would see the messages in the kernel log after they had been flushed in the `printk` call(s).

Comment: Thank you for reply, Is there any way to flush buffer outside of code. E.g. when you are debugging driver and don't see any messages from `printk`, can we trigger buffer flush from commandline?

Comment: Not explicitly, but calls to `[v]printk` or `printk_deferred` might flush your own module's messages as well. As the comment in line 1724, says "An earlier newline was missing, or another task also prints continuation lines...".